# Program after installed tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Nothing shows when type pip show tensorflow. and it give error after type import tensorflow as tf in python 2.7

[image]

Comment: I believe this is not tensorflow's problem but some package installing problem or path problem. Please check https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps described in the [Download and setup with anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/):

probably your anaconda is local while doing

```
sudo pip install tensorflow
```

is installing it globally.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Another question is that whether tensorflow has a IDE or do i have to program in terminal. I used a little bit Torch before, which has itorch, so I'm wondering whether tensorflow has something similar.

Comment: I tried to use ipython notebook. But it seems can't find tensorflow.

Comment: i run source activate tensorflow. Then ipython notebook. it opens notebook. I type import tensorflow as tf. it shows that error.